# Python - How to return the highest value from a list of dictionaries where the value is itself in a list?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this `list` of `dicts`:

```
>>> for player in players:
    print(player.show_hand())

'{'name': 'Tim', 'hand': [Card(rank='7', suit='diamonds', value=6), Card(rank='9', suit='spades', value=8)], 'score': 1}
 {'name': 'Manu', 'hand': [Card(rank='9', suit='clubs', value=8), Card(rank='7', suit='clubs', value=6)], 'score': 1}
 {'name': 'Kawhi', 'hand': [Card(rank='K', suit='diamonds', value=12), Card(rank='2', suit='clubs', value=1)], 'score': 1}
 {'name': 'Tony', 'hand': [Card(rank='Q', suit='clubs', value=11), Card(rank='3', suit='clubs', value=2)], 'score': 1}'
```

If there is only 1 player with the highest score i can return that player no problem:

```
score_list = []
for num in range(len(players)):
    score_list.append(players[num].show_hand()['score'])

winner = []
for player in players:
    if player.show_hand()['score'] == max(score_list):
        winner.append(player.show_hand()['name'])

if len(winner) > 1:
    print('draw')
    highest_card = []
    for player in players:
        if player.show_hand()['name'] in winner:
            print(player.show_hand()['name'])
            for num in range(2):
                highest_card.append(player.show_hand()['hand'][num].value)
            for num in range(2):
                if player.show_hand()['hand'][num].value == max(highest_card):
                    print('The Winner is ', player.show_hand()['name'])
    print(highest_card)

else:
    print('The Winner is ', winner)
```

If there are players with the same score because they had the same type of hand (Highest card for example) I want to iterate through the list and check each players `hand` which is a `list` for the highest `Card` `value` to determine the winner or if the game is a draw. This is where I am failing.

EDIT:

This is the output I am getting when all players `score` is 1 (highest card) or 2 (pair):

```
draw
Tim
The Winner is  Tim
Manu
The Winner is  Manu
Kawhi
The Winner is  Kawhi
Tony
[6, 8, 8, 6, 12, 1, 11, 2]
```

Card is a named tuple:

```
import collections


Card = collections.namedtuple('Card', ['rank', 'suit', 'value'])


class FrenchDeck:
    ranks = [str(n) for n in range(2, 11)] + list('JQKA')
    suits = 'spades clubs hearts diamonds'.split()
    card_values = [int(n + 1) for n in range(len(ranks))]

    def __init__(self):
        self._cards = [Card(rank, suit, value)
                       for suit in self.suits
                       for rank, value in zip(self.ranks, self.card_values)]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._cards)

    def __getitem__(self, position):
        return self._cards[position]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    FrenchDeck()
```

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? What happens if two or more players have the same highest value card?

Comment: Is Card here a class you controll? If so have you thought about implementing custom operator functions like __lt__ etc so that you can easily compare two card objects? Recently made a similar task as this as a test for possible interns where that was the recommended solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a new `key` `highest_card_value` to the `player` instance in the `players` `list`. Then I compare the `value` of the `Card` objects in `hand` and give `highest_card_value` the value of the highest card in the hand.

```
for player in players:
    player.show_hand()['score'] = score.define_score(player.show_hand()['hand'] + dealer.show_hand())
    if player.show_hand()['hand'][0].value > player.show_hand()['hand'][1].value:
        player.show_hand()['highest_card_value'] = player.show_hand()['hand'][0].value
    else:
        player.show_hand()['highest_card_value'] = player.show_hand()['hand'][1].value
```

I then loop through the values:

```
score_list = []
for num in range(len(players)):
    score_list.append(players[num].show_hand()['score'])

winner = []
for player in players:
    if player.show_hand()['score'] == max(score_list):
        winner.append(player.show_hand()['name'])
print(winner)

if len(winner) > 1:
    print('draw')
    highest_card = []
    for player in players:
        if player.show_hand()['name'] in winner:
            for num in range(2):
                highest_card.append(player.show_hand()['hand'][num].value)
    for player in players:
        if player.show_hand()['highest_card_value'] == max(highest_card):
            print('The Winner is ', player.show_hand()['name'])
    print(max(highest_card))

else:
    print('The Winner is ', winner)
```

Here is the output:

```
{'hand': [Card(rank='3', suit='spades', value=2), Card(rank='2', suit='diamonds', value=1)], 'name': 'Tim', 'highest_card_value': 2, 'score': 1}
{'hand': [Card(rank='Q', suit='clubs', value=11), Card(rank='7', suit='diamonds', value=6)], 'name': 'Manu', 'highest_card_value': 11, 'score': 1}
{'hand': [Card(rank='6', suit='hearts', value=5), Card(rank='A', suit='spades', value=13)], 'name': 'Kawhi', 'highest_card_value': 13, 'score': 1}
{'hand': [Card(rank='3', suit='diamonds', value=2), Card(rank='2', suit='clubs', value=1)], 'name': 'Tony', 'highest_card_value': 2, 'score': 1}
['Tim', 'Manu', 'Kawhi', 'Tony']
draw
The Winner is  Kawhi
13
```

Each played has the highest card `hand`, however Kawhi has the card with the highest value so he wins.